# What model-pairs are supported by the assistant decoding generation in Huggingface AutoModelForCausalLM?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model

## What model-pairs are supported by the assistant decoding generation in Huggingface AutoModelForCausalLM?

The assistant decoding model as described in https://huggingface.co/blog/assisted-generation is implemented in https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/22211

**Q Part 1.** What model-pairings are known to be supported by the `model.generate(..., assistant_model='')` feature?

**Q Part 2.** Does it work for decoder-only model too? Anyone tried any pairs of decoder-only models available on the huggingface hub?

---

The assumption for the assistant decoding model are:

- the tokenizer must be the same for assistant and main model
- the model is supported by `AutoModelForCausalLM`

```py
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

checkpoint = 'EleutherAI/pythia-1.4b-deduped'
assistant = 'EleutherAI/pythia-160m-deduped'

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint) #, bos_token_id=101, eos_token_id=102)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(checkpoint) #, bos_token_id=101, eos_token_id=102)

assistant_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(assistant)

tokenized_inputs = tokenizer("Alice and Bob", return_tensors="pt")

outputs = model.generate(**tokenized_inputs, assistant_model=assistant_model)

tokenizer.batch_decode(outputs, skip_special_tokens=True)
```

I've tried the following and this works:

- `EleutherAI/pythia-1.4b-deduped` + `EleutherAI/pythia-160m-deduped`

But these didn't:

- `google-bert/bert-large-uncased` + `google-bert/bert-base-uncased` (also had to add `, bos_token_id=101, eos_token_id=102)` to the model and/or tokenizer initialization to avoid None type when assistant model is scoping down the vocabulary)
- `FacebookAI/xlm-roberta-large` + `FacebookAI/xlm-roberta-base` (ended up with `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()` error when looking for candidate generation)

Comment: Also asked on https://stackoverflow.com/q/78156512/610569 and https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/22211